# How lubuntu works?

Tags: synaptic, lxterminal

I just installed lubuntu 16.04 but I do not know anything at all in how it works. How does it work?  Everything that I need to install, I just have to type it in the LXTerminal?  Or I have to search it at Synaptic Task Manager?

Comment: Open the Software Center and look for programs to install. Commercial software are not available there, you have to look for it on developers' page. To install common software via LXTerminal, run these commands: `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install software_name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be best suited to follow the Wiki entry for Lubuntu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation

Hope this helps!